# How to solve ODE quickly on GPU.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose standard ODE $y'(t) = f(t, y)$ where $y\in R^1$,  $y(t_0) = y_0$.

How to get precise solution $y(t_i)$ for $t_i \in [t_0, \dots, t_{N-1}]$ samples quickly?

Standard methods for solving this are Euler, RK, etc. But, what if the evaluation of $f(t, y)$ is time consuming? Is there a method on GPU, that can accelerate this?

I had an idea to sample $f(t, y)$ on some area $[t_0, t_{N-1}]\times[y_\min, y_\max]$ using GPU threads.  (Let's say $f_{ij} = f(t_i, y_j)$ )
which can be done quickly on GPU. Then, we can create integral curve on this $f_{ij}$ grid using some interpolation. Points $[t_i, y_i]$ can be considered as an approximated solution, and we can refine grid around this curve and evaluate $f(t_i, y_p)$ in the neighborhood and refine the solution...

Can this approach work or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 2):

A synopsis of parallel methods for ODEs can be found [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/whats-the-state-of-the-art-in-parallel-ode-methods). 
In particular, the [Parareal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parareal) method offers a strategy to integrate an ODE in parallel. Still, you need to perform serial evaluations of $f$ using a coarse scheme.

Comment: thanks, that looks promissing